# How to generate images from PDF files in php?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, pdf, imagick

I am using Imagick to product images from massive pdf files. I also want those images with `RGB` or `sRGB` color mode so `Internet Explorer` can display the images correctly.

I have tried

```
$im = new imagick($fileName.'[0]');
 //$im->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB); //try this already
 // $im->setImageColorSpace(1);   //try this already
  $im->setResolution(300,300);
  $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
  $im->writeImage($imageFile);
  $im->clear();
  $im->destroy();
```

I did get images but the color is way off with `setImageColorspace` and `setImageColorSpace` methods. (ex: color is inverted.)

If I comment out those methods, the images look right but some of them are not `RGB` mode and create problems in `Internet Explorer`.

I really need the `RGB` color mode on the images. Are there anyways to do it? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to encounter a problem with CMYK pdfs. Have you tried converting them to PNG? PNG -contrary to jpeg - only encodes RGB so the images will in any case be in the correct colorspace.

You might also want to have a look at ghostscript (the engine behind imagemagicks PDF conversion) and it's `--UseCIE` switch.

I wrote a php-wrapper to ghostscript which you can find at [github](https://github.com/heiglandreas/Org_Heigl_Ghostscript) that you might find usefull when you want to use ghostscript.